# How does the map function work in React.js?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, key

I'm following the ReactJS tutorial from www.tutorialpoints.com and I'm at [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_components.htm)

In a nutshell it provides the following data in JSON format:

```
this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Foo",
               "age":"20"
            },

            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Bar",
               "age":"30"
            },

            {
               "id":3,
               "name":"Baz",
               "age":"40"
            }
         ]
      }
```

and is looping through it with the **map** function below:

```
{this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />)}
```

What I fail to understand is why are they using a tuple (person, i) to target EACH object and how is the `key = {i}` part of the code working. I have tried removing the `key` part and the code still works. From further reading I understood that it helps reload only the specific data that has been changed instead of the whole dataset, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone go through ONLY the loop in that example line by line to clarify how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider your `.map()` returns 10 items. When you change one of the 10 item, say 5th item, React won't know which element to change in particular without the `key`. So, it will re-render the entire items of the `.map()`.

If you provide a `key`, the element with that `key` will be re-renders leaving the other 9 items undisturbed. This is to improve performance.

**[UPDATE]**

The `key` is reserved to identify an React element uniquely. It don't need to be `i`, it can be any random string. Personally, I use [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) to generate random unique key.

```
{this.state.data.map((person) => <TableRow key = {shortid.generate()} data = {person} />)}
```

React won't add it's reference `ids`(`data-reactid`) when you have a array of React elements. When you try to render that array, React will append your `key` to its `data-reactid` during normalization.

**Array of elements without `key`**

```
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1" role="row">
```

**Array of elements with`key`**

```
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1.$123" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1.$124" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1.$125" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1.$126" role="row">
<tr class="" data-version="1.0.0" data-reactid=".0.2.2.1.0.0.1.$127" role="row">
```

The number after `$` is the key value you supply to that component. By this, React can uniquely identify a component.

Latest version of React won't expose the `data-reactid` in the DOM.

[Read this for better understanding](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.ozmvqff09)

Comment: Instead of `{this.state.data.map(person => <TableRow data = {person} />)}` I can use the code provided in the question and all that logic will be run by React? Is the `key` variable reserved ONLY for that particular purpose? May you direct me to an example where it is easy to see it in action?

Comment: I see that you didn't provide a tuple `(person, i)` to the map function. Is it because you have a function to generate key?

Comment: Yes, I use shortid to generate a random string. I've added the link.