# Array seems filled untill i try to use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an Object with an array of items which I want to map through. When I console.log the Object it will return the Object and the filled array.

output from the console.log(this.props.pkmns)

```
{
  "pkmns": [
    {
      "url": "http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon-species/1/",
      "name": "bulbasaur"
   },
    {
      "url": "http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon-species/2/",
      "name": "ivysaur"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://pokeapi.salestock.net/api/v2/pokemon-species/3/",
      "name": "venusaur"
    }
  ]
}
```

When i specifically console.log the array it returns empty.

output from console.log(this.props.pkmns.pkmns):

```
[]
```

And the code

```
class PkmnContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(props){
    return this.props.startPkmn()
}

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {console.log(this.props.pkmns)}
        {console.log(this.props.pkmns.pkmns)}
        {this.props.pkmns.pkmns.map((pkmns)=>{
          <p>{pkmns}</p>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    'pkmns': state.pkmns
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  startPkmn: () => {
    return dispatch.pkmns.start()
  }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PkmnContainer);
```

What should I do to be able to map through this array?

[full code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjk75325po)

Comment: Can you write the outputs of the two first console.logs?

Comment: @MstrQKN: The outputs are the object and the empty array.

Comment: can you put your code in sandbox or jssfiddle beacause what you are doing as per the code your provided seems to be correct

Comment: I'm guessing this is a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I think this post can help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125854/how-does-the-map-function-work-in-react-js a bit

Comment: @JJJ I'm currently using async/await when fetching the data

Answer (score -4):

```
this.props.pkmns.pkmns.map((pkmns)=>{
      <p>{pkmns}</p>
    })
```

There seems to be a typo and a `pkmns` too many. Trys with `this.props.pkmns.map`.